# Z parameters to Input and Output Impedance Conversion Question

Tags: amplifier, impedance-matching, s-parameters

I have to design a matching network for [BGA7027](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/BGA7027.pdf) at approximately 870 MHz. My understanding goes that I should convert the S-parameters given in the datasheet to Z-parameters, from which I find Zin and Zout of my device, and then match those to 50 Ohms. The datasheet gives this table:

[image]

I tweaked values for 900 MHz a bit to get closer to 870 MHz so at the frequency of interest we get:

S11 = -0.893 + 0.223i ; S12 = 0.011 + 0.017i

S21 = 0.880 + 3.810i  ; S22 = -0.744 - 0.091i

I converted those to **Z-parameters** to get:

Z11 = 0.0113 + 0.0684i ; Z12 = 0.0029 + 0.0051i

Z21 = 0.1684 + 1.1423i ; Z22 = 0.0624 - 0.0205i

After that I try to find Z<sub>in</sub> and Z<sub>out</sub> using:

[image]

[image]

The main question is: is the Z<sub>L</sub> and Z<sub>S</sub> normalized impedance or its actual value? In other words, if S parameters have been characterized using 50 Ohm impedance, and my source and load impedances are the same, should I input 1 in place of source and load impedances in the equations above, as opposed to 50? I'm leaning towards it being normalized but haven't been able to find the exact mention of it anywhere. The other question is, if this approach to find Z<sub>in</sub> and Z<sub>out</sub> correct, or are there any fundamental mistakes in my reasoning?

Comment: I am unsure why you would take this approach via "\$Z\$", what I would do: use a circuit simulator which can handle S-parameters. Make model of the amplifier using the S11, S12 etc which you determined. Simulate that model in a circuit with 50 ohm input and output ports, confirm that you get the S11, S12 etc you specified. Then add matching components and tweak their values such that you get the S11, S12 etc. that indicate proper matching.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yup, I was going to use ADS to confirm my results, but wanted to do it manually first. Thinking knowing the actual input/output impedance first and then trying to match it might be more fool proof method than just trying to tune the values using simulation. But maybe you are right and just going straight to simulation is the rational way to do it.

Comment: do it manually before simulations by all means, but stay in S parameters throughout, no need to convert to other bases.

Comment: @Neil_UK Hmm, I guess I had erroneous conception of S parameters. I guess you mean using Zin = Z0*(1+S11)/(1-S11) and  Zout= Z0*(1+S22)/(1-S22) formulas?

Comment: See if you can find a 'how to' on the net to use the Smith chart graphically to match S-parameters (S for scattering, not Smith BTW), that's probably the most accessible way to do it manually, and it gives you an intuitive feel for what you're doing. Writing Z = f(S) is just transforming to a different base, and telling you nothing new, leaving you with exactly the same matching operating to be done in the new base, but with more obfuscation, chance of error, and less intuition.

Comment: Yeah I understand, just assumed that I have to use Z parameters for Z calculations, while ignoring the nature of S11 and S22 parameters (reflection coefficients). This is my first dive into using those techniques, so forgive the nonsensical conclusions..

Comment: Yes, you have to multiply Z parameters with Zo (i.e 50ohm). Then Zin and Zout will be in ohms. By the way, you have some wrong calculations in transforming from polar to rectangular. I didn't check throught.